# Am I Using Four Dimensions Correctly?

Tags: dimensions

My universe has four spatial dimensions. But there are only three-dimensional beings living inside it. For the sake of simplicity, the intelligent creatures are humans.

A planet exists in space. It is  divided into two parts in four-dimensional space: the “material” world where the humans are, and the “magical” world where all the magical energies are. There’s a midpoint between these two parts of the planet on the fourth axis, the material world on one side and the magical on the other. The humans, obviously, can’t see the magical energies because they are in a different place, technically. However, because both the humans and the magical energies only exist in three dimensions, they would, for all intents and purposes, overlap.

This is my idea so far. However, I am not an expert on this subject, and the research I’ve done about reaches the limits of what I understand. So my question is this: **Is this even how four spatial dimensions work?** Or is there something about the whole concept I’m not aware of that makes this not work? Admittedly the magic aspects aren’t very important to the actual question, but they make up practically the whole premise, so…

As I said, I’m not an expert, so I’m not sure I’ve gotten all the terminology correct.

Comment: Somewhat related https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/70068/30492

Comment: I'm a layman, but that reads ok to me. Both worlds occupy x0, y0, z0, but normal world is at w0 whereas magic world is at w1. The problem will be that magic by definition is not at w0, so cause and effect will be strictly limited. (I.e. neither party can move between w0 and w1). You'll need to define what is common to both worlds (light? to some extent?). If you want interaction, you might be better off with non magic users only perceiving 3 dimensions, while magicians perceive 4. I'm sure you won't lack for answers.

Comment: Hello Lea. Thanks for asking! But I'd like to point out that you might be asking the wrong question. We could use some input. the scientific concept of dimensions doesn't have a fourth spatial dimension, just three spatial dimensions plus time. Mathematically we can play with the idea of a fourth spatial dimension. Go look up a [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract), which can be thought of as the shadow of a four-dimensional cube (as a square can be thought of as a shadow of a three-dimensional cube). But is that really important? (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... I ask because it doesn't sound like you need a scientific expression of a fourth spatial dimension, It sounds like you could use help defining and developing what a fourth spatial dimension *means to your world.* In which case, whatever humanity has developed along the lines of "understanding" a fourth spatial dimension is completely irrelevant as we're helping you build rules for your unique imaginary world. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: (BTW, it's worth noting that we're no more capable of comprehending a fourth spatial dimension than a square is a third dimension... Any 4D object intersecting our world would look like a 3D slice of that object just as a 3D object intersecting a 2D world looks like a 2D object. please keep that in mind if you really want to stick with "science.")

Comment: [this](https://youtu.be/0t4aKJuKP0Q) might help you out

Comment: This question needs more research and more focus. For some visualization of the 4D concept check out https://miegakure.com/

Comment: Space already is 4D, with 3 local and a temporal coordinate.

Answer (score 5):

Let's throw a few basic tests at your understanding. If you can answer these questions, then your understanding of 4 dimensional space is accurate.

1. How thick are things in the 4th dimension? If someone moves an inch in that direction, are they still in the world? Would they fall off the "edge" of the planet?
2. Does light propagate into the 4th? If so, how does it maintain the square of the distance law?
3. How far apart are the real world and the magical world?
4. Can you rotate things along an axis that involves the 4th dimension? What would a person look like if they twisted that way?

4th dimensional geometry is hard. Just the rotation thing escapes most people. Let me know how this hits you. In most cases, you can wrap your head around it by replacing one of the current dimensions (like width or height) with the 4th, and thinking of it like a flatland.

In [The Planiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Planiverse), A.K. Dewdney explores some of the limitations in a gravitationally realistic 2d universe, and attempting to apply that to a 3d universe provides a few good insights.

Imagine if, for your typical side scroller (and where the entire world exists at once), if the character were pulled an inch out of the screen. What would happen? Would they fall through the virtual floor? Would the gravitational pull of the planet act in a Pythagorian manner and pull them back towards the center? If so, would they drag against the solid parts of the planet until they get caught in the magma at the center of their planet?

Remember that there isn't any "can see it but can't interact with it" in 4d reality. If you're in the same dimensional space with something, then the rules are the same regardless of what part of the dimensional space.

When writing the 4th dimension in my fiction, [here are the rules I decided to go with](https://thaumechanicalman.com/2022/04/the-widder/).

I decided that the 4th dimension is not, in fact, interchangeable with the other dimensions. Yes this breaks experimental invariance, since you couldn't move an experiment a foot to the widder and have it act the same as if it were in the nominal volume. I'm ok with this. I get to set the rules, and this makes for a better story.

I'd like to point out that nobody has ever demonstrated that the time dimension can experimentally be interchanged with the other dimensions and get the same result. We just do the math like it is (but negative) because it's convenient for explaining relativity.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but it is an excellent comment.

Comment: Actually, I think it does answer his question. He asked if this is how four dimensions work. I'm pretty sure the answer is "no, you're thinking of alternate dimensions, not a 4th spacial dimension," but that wouldn't be a useful answer. Instead, I provided a test to his reasoning to find out if the reality matches how he thinks four spacial dimensions would work. It's not what he actually asked for, but I think it's what he needs.

Comment: Even if proposed as a Frame Challenge, you're not providing an answer, you're not even challenging the premise. You're asking for details. That's a VTC reason. maybe it's just me, but trying to overcome a VTC reason isn't an answer when the details provided will create the context for an answer.

Comment: The problem is that, if you go strictly by the rules, this entire question would be closed as "would result in answers that are opinion" because it's asking how physics would work if physics were different, without being absolutely specific about what kind of different, and if he did there would be no question. I'm not really big on refusing to help people because they didn't follow Jeopardy rules and phrase their answer as a question.

Comment: That argument has been brought up in Meta many times. It's no longer valid because the community can't reach a consensus about it (i.e., the consensus is to ignore it). I didn't flag your answer for closure, but I am pointing out that asking for clarification as an answer isn't an answer. I am, however, delighted that you expanded your answer to better provide an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just a comment on your last paragraph: I have never ever heard any physics guy referring to the time dimension and the space dimensions as "interchangeable". The "just minus sign" is what makes the Minkowski metric of special relativity so... special and is of crucial importance. The time component of the 4-momentum is energy, while the spatial components are the space momentum. The time elements of the electromagnetic tensor are the electric fields, while the spatial components are the magnetic field. time and space are def not interchangeable. Not to mention general relativity

Comment: Yes, actually, I have. When dealing with black holes, I've had physicists translate the dimensions as a way to describe how event horizons could come into existence, or how an object could enter a black hole. I believe they do it out of a misunderstanding of experimental invariance.

Comment: all due respects, I would really question the credibility of those people as physicists. Most grad students wouldn't make that misunderstanding. In the context of general relativity in particular ( you say it was about black holes), nobody who has studied the topic past the introduction section would think that time and space are interchangeable in a Schwarzschild metric. It is possible that they just tried to explain something more informally, and got tripped up in the way they were trying to convey their idea in a simplified way.

Comment: The problem with black holes is that people are taught that they exist, and here are the formulas that apply to them, so they back-fit the formulas to suit their belief that they exist. The concept of a continuous collapsing object runs afoul of our difficulty with grasping infinities.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is

> Is this even how four spatial dimensions work?

But it is hard to answer, because you did not really explain how your 4th dimension work. In a mathematical sense, I have no idea what your 4d-geometry is like (is it euclidian, is it curved?), so it is hard to assess whether you have a correct understanding of it or not, because you simply do not give elements that would allow us to determine that. To be clear, you could define infinitely many different 4D spaces whose geometries work in wildly different ways

I would suggest that the tag "physics" is not appropriate here. Your question is about geometry,not physics. I would definitely strongly suggest to remove the "spacetime" tag cause it is very confusing in this context. You explicitely mention that you are not talking about time dimensions.

All I can do is point a few elements that you mention in the question and point out inconsistencies. I will leave all elements of magic aside because I did not understand any of it.

> A planet exists in space, and is divided into two parts in four-dimensional space: the “material” world where the humans are, and...

So, if I read this correctly, humans are 3D-entities but planets exist in 4 dimensions. There seems to be a clear geometrical distinction between humans and planets, for reasons unspecified. I don't know how the rest of what we call matter in our world works in yours (is a rock in 3D or in 4D? As a chunk of earth, I would assume it is a 4D element?).

Make sure to keep in mind that stuff in 4D will behave very weirdly for a 3D spectator. **As they move through the 4th dimension, solids will appear to grow, shrink, change shape, appear and disappear out of nowhere** from a restricted 3D point of view. Let's not even get started on the tears of pain of your scientists as they try to figure out 4D orbits from a 3D view. The night sky is going to be confusing. And those damn rocks that keep appearing everywhere really mess you up when you're driving... (see lower to find out why rocks keep accelerating)

> The humans, obviously, can’t see the magical energies because they are in a different place, technically

**humans can see things that are in a different place**. They can not, however, see energy (tho they may measure the consequences of it, such as photon emission and stuff).

> However, because both the humans and the magical energies only exist in three dimensions, they would, for all intents and purposes, overlap.

You would have to clarify what you mean by overlap, but **if you mean "be at the same position", then this is definitely not how the higher dimension works**. I don't understand what you mean by this sentence

As a more general, remark, you say the humans are only in 3D, but that a whole "half" of the 4th axis is dedicated to them (and the other to magic). That doesn't really make sense. **Either they are "filling" a part of the 4th D, or they are 3D** (in which case their 3D space should not intersect a whole section of the 4th axis but only one point (potentially a few if the geometry is curved))

Also, the fact that there is a special mid-way point along the 4th D breaks the most fundamental symmetries that we have in our physical universe (translation inveriance no longer holds true). By virtue of the Noether theorem, that will mean that momentum has no further reason to be conserved. **Our most fundamental physical laws will not hold in your 4D space**. That is going to be a weird, weird world where you might just get accelerated through 4D space for no apparent reason. Prepare to constantly see a whole lot of stuff popping in and out of geometrical existence around you in your 3D space, because I'm afraid **nothing can ever be at rest in the 4th dimension** (unless it reaches that mid-point maybe, you do have isotropy from there).

Answer (score 2):

**Kind of**

[image]

You are describing two 3D flatlands with a finite distance apart in the fourth dimension.  All the people and things are only 3-dimensional so live entirely in their slice. And they somehow have the ability to hop between slices.

This is entirely fine because the fourth spacial dimension is fiction. But you are not using all the tropes that people who like to talk about a fourth dimension like to use. We tend to like things moving continuously in the fourth direction and seeing 3D slices as they pass through out reality. You seem to just have two planets with places in one corresponding to places in the other one. Put another way you have infinite void, then material universe, then middle void, then spirit universe, then infinite void again.

I suggest reading Flatland by Edwin Abbot for an overview of the most common conception of 4D space. It is a classic. [It is in the public domain.](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/201) Or if books are too cool for you, there  are [loads of losers on Youtube with videos summarizing it.](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=flatland+explained) Don't be like those losers. Use your brain.

Answer (score 0):

Could be?

Since you already mentioned that magic is involved, it makes some things much easier.

The 4th dimension has to have discrete quantum levels (you are at 0 or 1 but never at 1.5).  Otherwise, there would likely to be a lot of bleed through.  In this case, each unit of the 4th dimension would be a discrete universe.  You could also have more than two universes.

If you create a large enough threshold energy for moving from one quantum state to another, you prevent accidental bleed through.

One theory that we can't test is that gravity is 4 dimensional.  That is why it is so weak for how slowly it drops off.  This would have the added benefit that planets and stars will likely occupy the same xyz from one quantum state to another.  The gravity of our Sun will pull on matter in the other universe and make it more likely that their sun will be in the same area.  You could use this to explain dark matter (that planet is at the same xyz but you can't interact with it because it is in a different universe.